# Erlang: what supervision tree should I end with writing a task scheduler?

Tags: erlang, task, behavior, scheduler, erlang-supervisor

Mostly in educational purposes I'm trying to write a task (task is an open_port({spawn_executable, Command})) scheduler.

I end up with the tree like

```
        supervisor
        |        |
scheduler        receiver
gen_event        gen_event
                     |
                supervisor
                     |
                dispatcher
                gen_server
                     |
                supervisor
                |    |   |
             task1  ... taskN
```

In other words:

1. top supervisor starts scheduler and receiver and makes sure they will be alive
2. receiver starts middle supervisor
3. middle supervisor starts dispatcher and makes sure it will be alive
4. dispatcher starts bottom supervisor
5. bottom supervisor starts tasks upon request and makes sure they are restarted in case of error
6. at any time scheduler is ready to accept a task with a timestamp it should be executed at
7. when timestamp is met it notifies some event_manager
8. receiver is then notified by the same event manager and passes the message to dispatcher through the middle supervisor
9. dispatcher has some business logic that is why it is not stateless, for example, some kind of tasks cannot be executed simultaneously
10. when all conditions are met dispatcher passes task to bottom supervisor which makes sure task is executed until normal exit is got or some thresold is bypassed
11. bottom supervisor returns back a message which is then passed up-up-up to some event manager
12. and scheduler eventually receives this message, removing task from its queue or reenqueueing it or something else

The questions are:

1. Am I using behaviours right?
2. Isn't the structure too complicated? (However, in future the system is going to become distributed.)
3. Is there a way to combine receiver+middle supervisor and dispatcher+bottom supervisor in two modules instead of four implementing 4 behaviours in the same time?
4. Or is there a way to combine receiver+dispatcher+bottom supervisor in one module, eliminating the need for middle supervisor, implementing gen_event+gen_server+supervisor behaviour at the same time?
5. Am I mistaken thinking of behaviours as of interfaces or multi-inheritance in OO languages? (That makes me ask questions 3 and 4.)

Thanks in advance.

P. S. IMO, on one hand, the structure is too complicated; on the other hand such a structure lets me make any of its blocks distributed (for example, many schedulers to one receiver, one scheduler to many receivers, many schedulers to many receivers, many dispatchers for each receiver and even many bottom supervisors for each dispatcher - every layer with is own supervision policy). Where is the balance point between complexity and extensibility?

Comment: To me the role of the scheduler is not clear, for what do you need an extra scheduler?

Comment: Consider a cron replacement to run tasks more precisely: more often than once a minute; with a business logic in/after running (i. e. after successfully running some task generate another task(s)); with custom error handling (restart/cancel/ignore/etc on error); distributed.

Comment: If you want OTP supervisor tree, there have to be supervisor tree so never ever put supervisor under anything else than supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is simplifying your design much more like:

```
        supervisor
        |        |
 dispatcher      |
 +scheduler      |
                 |
            supervisor
            |    |   |
         task1  ... taskN
```

The there is not much gain from having a separate scheduler sending events to a dispatcher which starts tasks etc.  Even in the light of distribution.

The dispatcher-scheduler can be probably quite simply done with the help of the timer module and can be a gen_server.  Timer can either send messages which you can process in the handle_info callback or call api functions of your gen_server.

You could also use the timeout functionality to wake up the gen_server after the next interval that would be even simpler since you don't have to worry abou canceling timers when you add a new "task".

The dispatcher/scheduler then calls `supervisor:start_child` to add working tasks.

Distribution can be added easily: dispatcher/scheduler can be on a separate node than the second level supervisor.  The tasks starting function can distribute further and maybe using the [pool](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/pool.html) module for load balancing.

To answer your five questions:

1. I suspect you are using gen_event where it is not needed, but since the modules itself are not needed its easily fixed by removing them.  gen_event is if you want to be able to register many handlers on one event source, you are using it 1:1.  Supervision trees are usually built with supervisors being the direct child of other supervisors.
2. Yes its too complicated, looks a bit like you would do it in OO languages with less expressive power.  And just to prepare for a maybe distribution its not necessary.  Refactoring in a functional language like Erlang is much easier than you probably think.  So start simple and split functionality if you see the need.

3+4. See my altogether different suggestion.

1. Its not ver OO like. Behaviours in OTP are only callback modules hiding the process mechanics in a generic module.

Even with the simple structure I suggested there is plenty of flexibility (brought to you by Erlang) because if you want to have multiple schedulers you can just use rpc to call the supervisor.  You can use [pool](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/pool.html) to automatically load balance distribution of tasks.  And the dispatcher part can be easily separated from the scheduler (both under the toplevel supervisor then) the you can have more common state separated from the scheduler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I considered such a structure myself too, but there is still a part that I don't quite understand. Dispatcher and scheduler will both have some specific business logic, that is why they should be implemented in different modules I think (and for the sake of distribution too). I again use OO approaches and they would definitely be two different classes in OO - sorry for that, maybe I'm mistaken in case of Erlang. And the thing that I don't understand - how should they communicate in this case? gen_event? Pid ! Message? what behaviour should be dispatcher then?

Comment: And the other question - can one module implement more than one behaviour? should one module implement more than one behaviour? how one module implement more than one behaviour?

Comment: To clarify what I wanted to achieve separating scheduler from dispatcher: I wanted something we call Inversion of Control in OO, i. e. when one class depends on the other, we introduce the third class and make both classes depend on the third, but no more on each other. gen_event event manager seems to be the right candidate to be the "third class" - after implementing scheduler and dispatcher as gen_event event handlers they no more need to know about each other. But in this case dispatcher should simultaneously implement gen_event and gen_server if I'm right.

Comment: I think you have to depart from OO thinking if you want to benefit from Erlang.  It has quite different approach than OO so the same techniques don't apply.  If you try to find a 1:1 match between OO approach and Erlang you won't get any benefits of using Erlang.

Comment: If you want to separate dispatcher and scheduler you can do so.  Make both gen_servers.  Communicate by calling API functions of your callback modules rather than sending messages.  A function API has always better encapsulation and is easier to understand and document.  What happens internally: the API functions call `gen_server:call` or `gen_server:cast` which will it cause to send a message behind the curtain, which next will cause your handle_call or handle_cast handler to be invoked.

Comment: But both of them still need to know about each other no matter they are using standard behaviour API - isn't that the problem? They are not loosely coupled.

Comment: From what you describe you don't want any gen_event handler for this.  gen_event is to distribute events to multiple runtime registrable "listeners" e.g. for logging purposes.  You can the register handlers that show select events on the screen, another handler hat writes the data to disk, and maybe a third handler that writes some events to syslog.

Comment: No you cant have two behaviours in one module, or at least if it would be even theoretical possible it is never done.

Comment: Scheduler will be subscribed to messages from dispatcher and vice versa - that's two handlers already. Then - loggers will surely appear, for simplicity I didn't mention them; of course successful task execution should be logged and every unsuccessful must be logged. If there is no gen_event and scheduler communicates with dispatcher directly, logging will be introduced within one of them and cohesion will be lowered - that's bad; or logging will be introduced near and injected into them, making it even more complex, than with scheduler and dispatcher implementing gen_event. Am I right?

Comment: I can't comment if they are coupled to tightly because that would depend entirely on the exact problem.  You are talking about 1:1 n:1 1:n n:m and whatnot relationships: are you absolutely sure you need them all?  Start simple and adapt the implementation later if you have a working start. It looks like your are over-designing it now, especially when new to Erlang.  Use the flexibility given to you by a dynamic language like erlang.  Many complicated OO patterns are coming from working around strict and static type checked languages.  You won't need these here.

Comment: BTW its not forbidden to +1 an answer that helps and accept the answer ;-)

Comment: When I try to +1 an answer it says I'm not registered. But how am I writing?

Comment: >> It looks like your are over-designing it now, especially when new to Erlang. << Yes, I'm doing so intentionally - I want to undestand how complex system is designed in Erlang. I've tried some simple things - and think I understand them rather well - and they are awesome. But OTP design principles are not that simple, especially with lack of documentation I think (on erlang.com I've found only a brief example for every behaviour, not covering something complex). I need something like best practices on using behaviours. Is there something like Gang of Four book in OO for Erlang?

Comment: For all logging just use the `error_logger` which is a read made event manager, you can subscribe to these events and if you start the SASL application on startup there is ready made file logging and browsing.  Gang of four book: no but not really necessary since design patterns (= macro expansion done by humans from the view of a LISP developer) is not necessary.  Behaviours are like design patterns built into the library but you won't need that much of them.  gen_server is used 90% of the time gen_event and gen_fsm the rest.

Comment: Thanks again! >> Behaviours are like design patterns built into the library but you won't need that much of them. gen_server is used 90% of the time gen_event and gen_fsm the rest. << That seems to be what I needed to hear. :)