# Erlang: How to properly dispatch a gen_server with start_child in a supervisor and call the API

Tags: erlang, dispatcher, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor, gen-server

I have a `gen_server` in my *cavv* application that I need to start first to execute a call to. I want to use a *command dispatcher* for this. For a short example, this it the `gen_server`'s API:

**a gen_server: cavv_user**

```
-module(cavv_user).

-behavior(gen_server).

-define(SERVER(UserId), {via, gproc, {n, l, {?MODULE, UserId}}}).

start_link(UserId) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?SERVER(UserId), ?MODULE, [UserId], []).

change_email_address(UserId, EmailAddress) ->
    gen_server:call(?SERVER(AggregateId), {execute_command, #change_user_email_address{user_id=UserId, email_address=EmailAddress}}).
```

Before I can call `cavv_user:change_email_address().` I need to start the `cavv_user`. I do this is as a `simple_one_for_one` child in a supervisor, like so:

**a supervisor: cavv_user_sup**

```
-module(cavv_user_sup).

-behaviour(supervisor).

-define(CHILD(ChildName, Type, Args), {ChildName, {ChildName, start_link, Args}, temporary, 5000, Type, [ChildName]}).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, []).

start_child(UserId) ->
    supervisor:start_child(?SERVER, [UserId]).

init([]) ->
    RestartStrategy = {simple_one_for_one, 1, 5},

    Children = [?CHILD(cavv_user, worker, [])],

    {ok, { RestartStrategy, Children} }.
```

The problem I am now facing is how to *dispatch* commands to a `cavv_user`. I want to make sure the proper user is started first using `start_child`, and then call the `cavv_user:change_email_address().`

I have found this anwser, to use a *dispatcher*: [Erlang: what supervision tree should I end with writing a task scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407721/erlang-what-supervision-tree-should-i-end-with-writing-a-task-scheduler/5418130#5418130)

So I created a command dispatcher and end up with a `cavv_user_dispatcher` and a `cavv_user_dispatcher_sup` that in turn contains the `cavv_user_dispatcher` and the earlier `cavv_user_sup`:

```
         cavv_user_dispatch_sup
            |               |
 cavv_user_dispatcher       |
       (gen_server)         |
                            |
                            |
                      cavv_user_sup
                        |   |   |
                 cavv_user_1...cavv_user_N
```

**The cavv_user_dispatcher**

This works beautifully.

The problem I am facing now is, how do I properly write the code in `cavv_user_dispatcher`? I am facing a problem with code duplication. How to properly call start_child and call the appropriate API of cavv_user?

Should I use some kind of `Fun` like so?

```
-module(cavv_user_dispatcher).

dispatch_command(UserId, Fun) ->
    gen_server:call(?SERVER, {dispatch_command, {UserId, Fun}}).

handle_call({dispatch_command, {UserId, Fun}}, _From, State) ->
    cavv_user_sup:start_child(UserId),
    Fun(), %% How to pass: cavv_user:change_email_address(..,..)?
    {reply, ok, State};
```

Or duplicate the `cavv_user`'s API like so?

```
-module(cavv_user_dispatcher).

change_user_email_address(UserId, EmailAddress) ->
    gen_server:call(?SERVER, {change_user_email_address, {UserId, EmailAddress}}).

handle_call({change_user_email_address, {UserId, EmailAddress}}, _From, State) ->
    cavv_user_sup:start_child(UserId),
    cavv_user:change_email_address(UserId, EmailAddress),
    {reply, ok, State};
```

Or should I re-use the *command records* from `cavv_user` into some kind of util to properly build them and pass them around? Maybe some better way to pass the function I want to call at `cavv_user`?

I would like to solve the problem in the best Erlang way as possible, without code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your dispatcher supposed to handle other commands?

- If yes then then how will the next command will come, I mean will the requester know the process pid of the user or not?

  - if yes then you need 2 functions, one to create a user, it will return the pid to the requester for next call, and one to handle next requests by sending the command to the given pid
  - if no, then you need also 2 functions, one to create the a user and store the user_id along with the user process pid and one to handle next request by retrieving the process pid and then forward it the command (I suppose this is what you want to do).
- if no then you don't need to handle any command and should pass directly the email address when creating the user process. Note that this is true for all cases since you need a different interface to create a user.

I would modify your code this way (not tested, it is too late :o) !)

```
-module(cavv_user_dispatcher).

create_user(UserId,UserMail) ->
    gen_server:call(?SERVER,{new_user,UserId,UserMail}).

% Args is a list of argument, empty if
% F needs only one argument (the user Pid)
dispatch_command(UserId, Fun, Args) ->  
    gen_server:call(?SERVER, {dispatch_command, {UserId, Fun,Args}}).

handle_call({dispatch_command, {UserId, Fun,Args}}, _From, State) ->
    Pid = get_pid(UserId,State),
    Answer = case Pid of
        unknown_user_id -> unknown_user_id;
        _ -> apply(Fun,[Pid|Args]),
             ok
    end,
    {reply, Answer, State};
handle_call({new_user,UserId,UserMail},_From,State) ->
    % verify that the user id does not already exists
    CheckId = check_id(UserId,State),
    {Answer,NewState} = case CheckId of 
        false -> {already_exist,State};
        true  -> {ok,Pid} = cavv_user_sup:start_child(UserId,UserMail)
                 {ok,[{UserId,Pid}|State]}
                 % State must be initialized as an empty list in the init function.
    {reply, Answer, NewState};
...
get_pid(UserId,State) ->
    proplists:get_value(UserId, State, unknown_user_id).
check_id(UserId,State) -> 
    not proplists:is_defined(UserId, State).
```

and the user supervisor mus be modified this way:

```
start_child(UserId,UserMail) -> % change arity in the export
supervisor:start_child(?SERVER, [UserId,UserMail]).
```

and then the user server:

```
start_link(UserId,UserMail) ->
gen_server:start_link(?SERVER(UserId), ?MODULE, [UserId,UserMail],[]).

init([UserId,UserMail]) ->
    {ok,[{user_id,UserId},{user_mail,UserMail}]}.
```

Comment: I get it. The dispatcher should call start_child, and return a Pid. Then I should use the Pid and pass it into cavv_user:change_email_address(UserRef, EmailAddress) as a reference to the process, as the process could in theory also be started on another machine in the future. I am now passing User_Id's around, which is a bad thing in my design.

Comment: You can do as you say, the inconvenient is that the caller need to know the process ID which is a weird information to exchange (meaningless, subject to change...), the code I propose you stores the pair `{UserId,Pid}` in a proplist, it is a very simple implementation and I think that an ets should be better, also it doesn't show how to manage the death of the user process so in that state, the proplist is never cleaned, and a user cannot reconnect, but it is a starting point to try to answer your question.